# Не могу понять как устроен поток приложения

Tags: android

В любом логе при падении приложения я наблюдаю что дергается какой то `Handler`, затем `ApplicationThread` и далее до какого-то `Zyganote...` (вроде). Из этого я сделал вывод, что при запуске приложения система создаёт для него поток. И если происходит ошибка, то ломается все вплоть до фатального конца и дергается поток приложения. Оно вылетает. Но дело не в этом

Допустим, я хочу как-то овладить одним приложением, а именно перейти на одну его активность и нажимать на кнопки/вводить тексты/скроллить и т.д. Это возможно? Если нет, то почему? Как же тогда некоторые приложения умудряются показывать свои `view` поверх всего, работать даже когда закрыты.

**Clean Master** показывает кружок поверх всех других приложений для "ускорения" ;) системы.

**UC Browser** каким-то образом даже определяет когда пользователь что-то копирует и предлагает поискать через себя выделенный текст. Причём, работает прекрасно везде.

**Google Переводчик** обладает таким же функционалом, только предлагает перевести выделенный текст.

**Shazam** когда слышит музыку может автоматически начинать её искать

Да что там говорить, **Google Now** вечно слушает речь и откликается на "О'кей гугл"!

Как это все реализовывается?

И ещё. Не пойму как вообще устроена система. Можно поподробнее узнать об этом? Как работают прикладные и системные приложения? Почему некоторые разрешения обычные приложения получить не могут? Как работает отдел системы, отвечающий за хранение свернутых приложений?

Неужели весь андроид построен на приложениях и скриптах? Хотел бы увидеть стоящий ответ

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Из этого я сделал вывод, что при запуске приложения система создаёт для него поток.

Любое работающее приложение имеет хотя бы один поток (который называется обычно main thread). Нет потока - нет выполнения.

Андроид создает специальный процесс Zygote, который стартует виртуальную машину, которая уже загружает процесс (раньше это были dex файлы, как теперь - нужно смотреть).

> Допустим, я хочу как-то овладить одним приложением, а именно перейти на одну его активность и нажимать на кнопки/вводить тексты/скроллить и т.д. Это возможно?

и да и нет. Обычным приложениям нельзя влиять напрямую на другие - они запускаются в отдельном окружении-песочнице. Но можно взаимодействовать через посылку intend.

Что бы показать свое view поверх другого не объязательно "овладевать приложеним". Можно просто отображать свое окно с правильными настройками. Ключевое слово для поиска - пермишн android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW и, например, этот вопрос https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20461979/how-to-overlay-views-in-other-apps

> работать даже когда закрыты.

то, что вы якобы "закрываете" приложение, ещё не значит, что Вы его закрываете. Приложение вполне может запустить сервис и спокойно выжирать батарейку, показывая окно.

> UC Browser каким-то образом даже определяет когда пользователь что-то копирует и предлагает поискать через себя выделенный текст. Причём, работает прекрасно везде.

У андроида есть специальное апи, которым можно перехватывать изменения буфера обмена https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11500349/android-implement-broadcast-receiver-for-clipboardmanager

> Да что там говорить, Google Now вечно слушает речь

некоторые приложения имеют специальные привелегии:)

> И ещё. Не пойму как вообще устроена система. Можно поподробнее узнать об этом? Как работают прикладные и системные приложения? Почему некоторые разрешения обычные приложения получить не могут? Как работает отдел системы, отвечающий за хранение свернутых приложений?

тут расписывать на несколько книг. А система устроена просто - внизу линуксовое ядро, поверх - система для запуска андроид приложений и всякое разное для обслуживания камеры, микрофона, динамика и тому подобное. Ещё выше - высокоуровневое апи, в том числе vendor api. Ещё выше - обычные приложения.

> Неужели весь андроид построен на приложениях и скриптах? Хотел бы увидеть стоящий ответ

А как по другому?

Comment: Воу, спасибо)))